# AS3 - LocalConnection Error #3691: Resource limit for this resource type exceeded

Tags: actionscript-3, localconnection

I am using LocalConnection Object to send record messages on other SWF.

My code is below.

```
var outgoing_lc:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
outgoing_lc.send("_log_output", "displayMsg", outStr)
```

noting much complicated, its working in almost machines , but when i Run this is MAC machine it throws below error

```
Error #3691: Resource limit for this resource type exceeded.

LocalConnection/send()
```

Can anybody have any idea?? why such error comes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a look at this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html#send()  And try to divide your data into sub 40k chunks

Comment: Thanks @Dale Sattler, for your reply.. i tried by dividing my data with 35k chunks.. still i get the same issue on MAC